# KnockoutJS - not binding more than the first binding found in the HTML

Tags: knockout.js

Beginner question:

I have a simple viewModel and several `<div>` elements with simple `data-bind="text: property"` bindings.

The binding only works for the first such `data-bind` in the HTML.

Example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clrudolphi/ucAUC/
In the example, I have defined 7 `<div>`s with bindings.  The first 4 look like this:

```
       <div id="eagleMain" >
           <div class="eagle-num" data-bind="text: num" />
           <div class="eagle-name" data-bind="text: name" />
           <div class="eagle-date" data-bind="text: date" />
           <div class="eagle-current" data-bind="text: current" />
       </div>
```

The script looks like this:

```
var eagle = {
  num: '2',
  name: "John",
  date: "Jan 1, 2011",
  current: "student",
  memories: "camping",
  projectName: "Clothing Drive",
  projectDescription: "lorem ipsum"
};

ko.applyBindings(eagle);
```

The only div that receives a value is the first (bound to the 'num' property).
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not short-cutting the tags using `/>`. It only works for `span`.

Go for:

```
<div class="eagle-num" data-bind="text: num"></div>
<div class="eagle-name" data-bind="text: name"></div>
<div class="eagle-date" data-bind="text: date"></div>
<div class="eagle-current" data-bind="text: current"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

@nEEbz beat me to it.

Solution at:
http://jsfiddle.net/fZYVb/1/